# How to get the value of a calculation in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

So, I'm just starting out with jQuery (I know people will probably say 'you don't need jquery for this, just use js', but I am learning jquery first, then js).

I'm making a simple pizza calculator. You input the quantity of pizzas, pizza diameter and price and the calculator will tell you the Sq Inches of the pizza and the cost per square inch. I will add a second set of inputs later, and will compare the two answers to see which pizza deal is the best value.

http://jsfiddle.net/mildrenben/Zr2Wa/

The fiddle above shows where I'm. I can calculate the Sq Inches no problem. I then need to use the value of the Sq Inches in the next calculation for cost per Sq In, but can't figure out how to pass the information along.

Any help would be much appreciated!

HTML:

```
<form>
<input class="qty" placeholder="# of pizza's"></input>
<input class="diameter" placeholder="Pizza diameter (In)"></input>
<input class="price" placeholder="Price"></input>
</form>
<div class="button">Calculate</div>
<h3>Sq Inches</h3>
<div class="sqinAnswerContainer"></div>
<h3>Cost per Sq In</h3>
<div class="costsqinAnswerContainer"></div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
$(".button").click(function() {
    var qty = $("input.qty").val();
    var dia = $("input.diameter").val();
    var price = $("input.price").val();
    var pi = Math.PI;

    $(".sqinResult").after("<p class='sqinAnswer'>" + ((dia*dia)*pi.toFixed(2)) + "</p>");

    var sqinAnswer = $("p.sqinAnswer").val();

    $(".costsqinResult").after("<p>" + sqinAnswer + "</p>");


    });
});
```

Comment: Actually you're learning some JS while you learn jQuery because jQuery IS JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try .text instead of val?  Obviously, you'll want to get the units worked out

```
var sqinAnswer = $("p.sqinAnswer").text();
$(".costsqinResult").after("<p>" + sqinAnswer/price + "</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I suposed that you want include the results inside of divs squinReults and costsquinResults, in this case I recommended you to use append instead of after, additionaly you can store ((dia*dia)*pi.toFixed(2)) in one variable before set in place, like this:

```
var squinResults = ((dia*dia)*pi.toFixed(2));

$(".sqinResult").append("<p class='sqinAnswer'>" + squinResults  + "</p>");

var sqinAnswer = squinResults / $(".price").text();

$(".costsqinResult").append("<p>" + sqinAnswer + "</p>");
```

Can you tell us what is exactly what you want to put in costsquinResults?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method - http://jsfiddle.net/Zr2Wa/4/

```
$(".button").click(function() {
        var qty = $("input.qty").val();
        var dia = $("input.diameter").val();
        var price = $("input.price").val();
        var pi = Math.PI;

        var sqin = (dia*dia)*pi.toFixed(2);
        var sqinTotal = qty * sqin;
        var costPerSqIn = (price / sqinTotal).toFixed(2); 

        $(".sqinResult").after("<p class='sqinAnswer'>" + sqinTotal + "</p>");
        $(".costsqinResult").after("<p>" + costPerSqIn + "</p>");            

    });
```

EDIT: calculating cost per square inch